# Not able to host Web Applicantion on local IIS because VS2010 "OK" button gets disabled

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

VS2010 -> File -> New Project ->ASP.Net Web Application template -> Location :- i type as http://localhost/
"OK" Gets disabled.Can anyone help on this?. i was reffering tutorial at www.spiderdotnet.com and there same procedure was written we create web app and host it on local.
lINK IS http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/AspNet-Tutorial-64.aspx

Answer (score 3):

ASP.Net Web Applications, like all other ordinary project types, live on your hard disk.
You should select a normal folder.

After you finish writing your app, you can *deploy*  it to IIS.

Comment: i know above procedure. So is this not possible to do by directly as mentioned in tutorial typing http://localhost automatically virtual folder will be created and hosted??

Comment: The tutorial is probably referring to Web Site projects, which are deprecated.